# Changing backslash behaviour on Tomcat/Coyote

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm hosting a series of REST services on a tomcat server and many of them can use a backslash \ as part of the Id of the entity as in `http://server/entitype/id\of\the\entitythatcan/have/forwardslashes/too`

Now tomcat as I have discovered doesn't provide a way to change the two default behaviors, either return error on backslash found on URL or replace the \ with a forwardslash. See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/coyote/tomcat5/CoyoteAdapter.java.html Line 735

Is there any hope of changing this without having to make a custom build of tomcat?

Comment: Your entity URLs are invalid. That's the problem you should be fixing.

Comment: @EJP there is no fixing for that because I interact with external systems that don't like to play nice

Comment: Have you tried this on a supported version of Tomcat? Tomcat 5 has been dead for a long time.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz yes, the code is actually from tomcat 6/7, the url says tomcat5 but that's where the code comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to do, I have desisted of this long ago and suggest others to find their own workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `org.apache.catalina.connector. CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH` system property on Tomcat's [System Property Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html) (note that the reference is for Tomcat 7: you'll have to look at TC6's documentation if you are using TC6 to see if that's an option).

Comment: this flag was enabled on tomcat 6.0.17 if my memory doesn't fail me, but what it does is to enable the replacement of \ with /, not to actually allow backslashes as the name suggest, my hope was that there was an easy way to modify the behavior of the Coyote Adapter, but the only option seems to be to create a custom  tomcat build.

Comment: You could always ask on the TC devs list.